# How to Implement Option Recognition in C Programming for Linux

Tags: c

I'm programming in C at a Linux environment, and I'd like my program to recognize options like '-' or '--' for execution. I wonder how do programmers typically implement this?

In my case, I made the `main` function receive `argc`, `argv` arguments. Is that correct?

```
// headers

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // my codes
}
```

Comment: @G.M. Oh, yes, this question seems to be the answer. It seems there are various ways to recognize options. Choosing one among several methods is at the discretion of the programmer, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and I'd like my program to recognize options like '-' or '--' for
> execution. I wonder how do programmers typically implement this?

Programmers have two ways:

- write the option parser themselves
- use the ready-made library. The most popular is [`getopt`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html)  ([more listed here](https://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2018/08/31/a-survey-of-argument-parsing-libraries-in-c-c/))